# Search Tags in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello everyone the search is not working. For example the tags contain Php, Ajax, HTML 5 when you search Php or Ajax there is a result but if you search two words or more such as HTML 5 there is no result.

my model Codes:

```
public function getTagsMatch($limit=null, $tags, $offset=null) {
        $match = $tags;
        $this->db->from('threads');
        $this->db->where('status', 1);
        $search_query_values = explode(' ', $match);
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($search_query_values as $key => $value) {
        if ($counter == 0) {
            $this->db->like('tags', $value);
        }
            $counter++;
        }
        $this->db->order_by('pin_post', 'DESC');
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        $this->db->offset($offset);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well...

```
$search_query_values = explode(' ', $match);
```

This line takes in query values and "[explodes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)" the string using spaces. So if you input "HTML 5", it will actually search for tags like "HTML" or "5". Consider using a different character for exploding.

For example:

```
$search_query_values = explode(',', $match);
```

And the function call would be something like this:

```
getTagsMatch(NULL, 'Ajax,HTML 5,PHP', NULL);
```

A few more notes:

1. Default parameters should be at the end of an argument list (`function foo(bar0, bar1=0, bar2='') { ... }`, not randomly placed).
2. Consider using less variables. There is absolutely no reason to have `$tags`, `$match` *and* `$search_query_values` - one is enough. You might consider using 3 variables a semantic advantage, but it actually makes your code more difficult to read.

Comment: Its working now ^_^ the problem is not on my model thanks for your help

Comment: @ClintonCanarias, I am glad if my answer helped you. Please accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: It might confuse the readers the problem is only in my Controller but since you do effort to help me I just made Up Vote.. ^_^ Happy new year dude.

Comment: Likewise! I'm glad you solved the problem. And you are absolutely right, if the problem was something else entirely, my solution should not be accepted. But in that case it will be beneficial to others if you post your own solution and mark it as accepted. I'm personally curious what the problem was.

Comment: I just posted it I hope you understand my explanation because Im not good with explaining something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of this was on my controller because. I customize the tags but the fact is Im having a trouble how to explain this since Im not good in explaining such thing. I will just post some of the codes with some explanation.

My tags search will base on what is the tags slug for example website.com/tags/html-5

so my controller codes:

```
public function tags($tags) {
  $tag = search_title($tags);
  $data['result'] = $this->topic_model->getTagsMatch($tag);
}
```

and my search_title function code:

```
function search_title($str, $separator = '&nbsp') {
        $str = ucwords(strtolower($str));

        foreach (array('-', '\'') as $delimiter) {
            if (strpos($str, $delimiter)!==false) 
            {
                $str =implode($delimiter, array_map('ucfirst', explode($delimiter, $str)));
            }
        }
        $str = str_replace('-','&nbsp',$str); 
        $str = str_replace('%20','&nbsp',$str); 
        $str = str_replace('%26','&',$str); 
        $str = str_replace('%27','&nbsp',$str); 
        $str = str_replace('%28','&nbsp',$str); 
        $str = str_replace('%29','&nbsp',$str); 
        return trim(stripslashes($str));
    }
```

the problem of it is on this line

```
$data['result'] = $this->topic_model->getTagsMatch($tag);
```

so I change the **$tag** to **str_replace("-"," ",$tags)**

Comment: In other words, you had "Html-5" instead of "HTML 5" that you were searching for. Thank you! Makes sense. I am really glad you figured it out.